# Is there a name for this shape?

Tags: geometry

Consider some closed differentiable curve $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. At each point $p$ on the curve, draw the line $t(p)$ tangent to the curve. Let $S$ be the union of $t(p)$ for all $p\in\mathcal{C}$. I want to know if the set $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S$ has a name.

For a convex curve $\mathcal{C}$, $\partial(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S)=\mathcal{C}$ (take $\mathcal{C}$ to be a circle, for example). But for a non-convex curve, I expect $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S$ to be contained by the shape whose boundary is $\mathcal{C}$.

Below is an example of the construction I am talking about. The curve $\mathcal{C}$ is the hyperbola $y^2-x^2=1$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=3$ stitched together. Forgive me for the curve not being differentiable at four points! Imagine that those corners are smoothed out. I plotted the relevant tangent lines that identify the central diamond shape which corresponds to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S$. If I included all tangent lines (and assuming the corners are smoothed out), the only part of this graph that wouldn't be blue is this diamond.
[image]

Edit: I realize there may be some confusion based on the way I plotted this example. The closed curve is a hyperbola for $|x|<1$ and a circle for $|x|>1$, the tangent lines extending past the circle are not part of the hyperbola.

Comment: Could you draw an example?

Comment: Yes I can! I'll come back with a drawing.

Comment: The "diamond" in your example consists of just the origin by itself, since there are tangents to the curve which pass arbitrarily close to the origin.  The line $\ y=\left(\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\right)x+\epsilon\ $, for example, is tangent to the curve $\ y^2-x^2=1\ $ at $\ x=\frac{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}{\epsilon},y=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ $ and passes through the point $\ x=0,y=\epsilon\ $.

Comment: I am not considering the full hyperbola as part of the closed curve. The curve becomes the circle when $|x|>1$. The lines extending off past the circle are the tangent lines. Maybe I should have made the tangent lines a different color?

Comment: You are wondering if there exists a name for the complementary area swept by tangents , i.e., the set of points from which no tangent to the curve can be drawn

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, the aim of this question is to know whether this shape has any significance in the mathematical literature, as something with a name might have.